# Bash expand variable inside osascript command

Tags: bash

Can someone tell me how to make the variable expand in the following, please:

```
MESSAGE="Public IP Address has changed"
osascript -e 'tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to display \ 
dialog "My message is ${MESSAGE} " buttons {"OK"} with icon stop'
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! Would be great if you could explain your question a bit more by editing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes are preventing variable expansion: [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes)

```
MESSAGE="Public IP Address has changed"
osascript -e 'tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to display \ 
dialog "My message is '"$MESSAGE"' " buttons {"OK"} with icon stop'
# ....................^^........^^
```

I'm using shell string concatenation there:

- a single quote to close the first part of the single quoted string,
- the variable expanded within double quotes,
- a single quote to open the last part of the single quoted string.

Comment: Also, you can't use line continuation (with an escaped newline) in the middle of a single-quoted string.